# Bash Script that works with Jenkins to move into a specific directory and remove the oldest folder in that directory

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have a devbox that I ssh into as the Jenkins user, and as the title says, I want to run a bash script that will move to a specific directory and remove the oldest directory. I know the location of the specific directory.

For example,

ssh server [move/find/whatever into home/deploy and find the oldest directory in deploy and delete it and everything inside it]

Ideally this is a one-liner. Not sure how to run multiple lines while sshing as a part of a Jenkins task. I read some Stack Overflow posts on them, but don't understand it. Specifically 'here documents'.

The file structure would look like home/deploy and inside the deploy directory has 3 folders: oldest, new, and newest. It should pick out the oldest (because of it's creation date, and rm -rf it)

I know this task removes the oldest directory:

```
rm -R $(ls -lt | grep '^d' | tail -1  | tr " " "\n" | tail -1)
```

Is there any way I can adjust the above code to remove a directory inside of a directory that I know?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a script to ssh. Save the below script as

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/deploy
rm -R $( ls -td */ | tail -n 1 )
```

delete_oldest.sh and pass it to ssh like below

```
ssh server -your-arguments-here < delete_oldest.sh
```

**Edit:**

If you wish to place the script on the remote machine, first you could
copy the script from the local machine to the remote machine to  your
home folder using scp like this :

```
scp delete_oldest.sh your_user_name@remotemachine:~
```

Then you can do something like :

```
ssh your_user_name@remotemachine './delete_oldest.sh'
```

`'./delete_oldest.sh'` assumes that you're currently at your home folder on the remote machine which will be the case when you use ssh, as the default landing folder will always be the home folder.

Please try it with a test folder before you proceed.

Comment: What are my arguments? Do I just save the bash script in the home directory, or is anywhere fine? @sjsam

Comment: arguments are the usual ssh arguments. You may not have any arguments, that is OK.You could save the script anywhere and give the full path to it like `/path/to/delete_oldest.sh`

Comment: I am putting it in the deploy folder. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would run:

ssh server < /deply/delete_oldest.sh ? @sjsam

Comment: The script should be present in the computer where you give ssh. If you are giving the ssh command at machine1, the script should also be present in machine1.

Comment: I want to place it in my remote machine, the machine that I SSH to, not the machine that I SSH with though. Does that make sense? =/ @sjsam

Comment: to reiterate, here are the steps:

1. ssh into the server
2. go to home/deploy
3. create a file called delete_oldest.sh which has:
cd ~/deploy
rm -R $( ls -td */ | tail -n 1 )
4. add to Jenkins task:
ssh server cd /deploy < delete_oldest.sh

Is that right? why does the delete_oldest.sh need to cd into deploy when it's already in that directory?

Comment: You step2  `go to home/deploy` is not needed. In fact that is what `cd ~/deploy` does.

Comment: So you want me to save the file in the home directory. But the bash script I use for Jenkins is:

   'ssh server cd /deploy < delete_oldest.sh'

Which essentially moves into /deploy and looks for delete_oldest.sh and tries to execute it, but it can't. So then my bash script for Jenkins should actually be just ssh server < delete_oldest.sh.

Then my delete_oldest.sh (from the home directory) will cd into /deploy and find the oldest folder and delete it. Correct?

Comment: Your question says the `deploy` folder is inside the `home` directory. So the path is `/home/deploy`. Isn't it?

Comment: But in your previous comment, you said you use `cd /deploy`. Is the server chrooted to /home ?